# how to count the number of mean that above some value

Tags: python, pandas

Hi need help in some Pandas Cod !
the question is how TAKE the df and groupBy age Score mean and compare it to the df['Score'].mean
and count the result that above df['score'].mean the result of the count also need to groupBy age
here where I am right now :

```
data.groupby(['age'])['Score'].mean()
```

I get the mean score group by age

now how I compare it too the total score mean and count the result group by age

Comment: Sample Input and expected output please.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want:

1. A flag to show if the group mean is above the global mean
2. The number of records in each group that's above global mean.

   ```
   (
        df.groupby('age')
        .apply(lambda x: [x.Score.mean()>df.Score.mean(), x.Score.gt(df.Score.mean()).sum()])
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .set_axis(['group_mean_above_global_mean', 'num_above_global_mean'], axis=1)
        .reset_index()
   )
   ```

If you just want the number of groups that has a mean above the global mean, you can do:

```
(
    df.groupby('age')
    .apply(lambda x: x.Score.mean()>df.Score.mean())
    .sum()
)
```

Comment: Hi  It is not real what I am looking for . I need to see in the result all age group and the number of cell for each group that the cell score  is above the score mean

Comment: for example if in group age "18-25" there is 2 record that the score is above the score mean

Comment: I thought the first code block gives you that. Maybe it's easier if you show us an input dataframe and expected output dataframe example.